Highchart after upgrade giving error in the console logs. Errors “cannot read properties of undefined “length”
I have a LineChart which is breaking after upgrade to latest Highcharts 11.4.7.
Getting this error in console logs like:

Cannot read properties of undefined "length".

Getting error in insertItem() function.
insertItem: function(A, t) {
    var i, e = A.options.index, o = t.length;
    for (i = A.options.isInternal ? o : 0; i < o + 1; i++)
        if (!t[i] || a(e) && e < T(t[i].options.index, t[i]._i) || t[i].options.isInternal) {
            t.splice(i, 0, A);
            break
        }
    return i
}

t is coming as undefined.
Not able to identify when and how the value is passed to this method causing this error.
Is there any specific change needs to be done here while upgrading highcharts?
Expected to chart load with x-axis and y-axis information
More info on the implementation : We are using highcharts in mvc and we are using the default method createChartXYComponent for instantiation. And inside this method the error is getting triggered. I believe this code is generated by HighCharts.
@using Highsoft.Web.Mvc.Charts 
    @{
     var chart = new HighChartExtension();
     chart.YAxis[0].StartOnTick = false;
    }

I am assigning all the chart related properties from razor view and
calling the method in Highsoft.
@Html.Highsoft().Highcharts(chart, "XYComponent")

also in script we are calling few methods for initialization in document ready but it is throwing error.
$(document).ready(function () {
            createChartXYComponent();
    });

But createChartXYComponent is throwing error in console. All this is happening after upgrade from 8.2 to 11.4.7.

Hi @Anju Raman, Could you share your chart configuration object? A basic line chart works fine in Highcharts v11.4.7. For example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pw6dxeo7/

Hi @ppotaczek, Please find my fiddle link for reference. https://jsfiddle.net/anjuraman090/u502cfbp/9/  . In fiddle it is giving me another error like Uncaught TypeError: Highcharts.chart is not a constructor"

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, not to the comment section and not to any external ressource

@Anju Raman that's because you can not use new keyword with Highcharts.chart method. Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/efs8g9yx/

We are using highchart in mvc and we are using the default method createChartXYComponent() for instantiation. And inside this method the error is getting triggered. I believe this code is generated by HighCharts. Any idea how we modify this ?

Hi @Anju Raman, There is no HighChartExtension object in the official Highcharts .NET wrapper. The official wrapper uses HighchartsRenderer object and later RenderHtml() method. You can find more examples here: https://dotnet.highcharts.com/Highcharts/Demo

HighChartExtension is a custom class inheriting form Highcharts class. It was previously working in this way.

Hi @Anju Raman, There have been many breaking changes since version 8.2, so the integration does not guarantee backward compatibility with such old solutions. You need to follow the examples on the official page.

Thanks @ppotaczek Making code changes accordingly to accomodate with the upgraded version
